# iPhone Application map animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, maps

I'm new to Xcode and cocoa touch, but I'm planning on creating an app with the following requirement:

My app will contain a map, of only the local area( where I reside – this app is directed at our local community).

I already have a rather detailed map of the area that I'm targeting – very similar to what you would get on google maps. It has a few additional locally relevant landmarks and information.
I want to simulate the google maps app, with respect to the following features:

1. Just like google maps, when the user initially opens the app, he
   should see very few places(the major landmarks only).
2. On double tap to zoom he should be able to see more stuff.
3. If he moves around , it should add more locations, depending on
   which directions he has moved.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction with respect to:

- basic apple frameworks
- tutorials
- books
- open source apps or any other information that is relevant to what I
  need to do

*I'd like to reiterate, that using Apple Maps or Google Maps directly in my app is not an option, I need to use the map I have.*

Comment: There are several books on iOS, but I haven't read any, so I can't tell which ones are good. However, I have spent quite some time reading Apple's documentation, so my answer focuses on that. Also, I have included a couple of links towards apple code samples for handling cocoa touch events and gestures. You can start by looking to them and you will learn more than just handling events. There are many other sample codes, for pretty much everything. Just go looking for them on apple dev center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **For this project, you will need to:**

- Know the Objective-C language

  - [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- Be familiar with of Cocoa Touch

  - [Cocoa Touch - iOS Technology Overview](https://developer.apple.com/ios/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150322044205/https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/cocoa-touch.html))
  - [iOS Technology Overview - The Cocoa Touch layer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160826234655/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSTechnologies/iPhoneOSTechnologies.html)
- Check

  - [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html)

### **Drawing your map on a view**

To display your map, you will need to have knowledge in:

- [views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) (see the [View programming guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html), especially
  [View and Window Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html))
- [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/)
- [Drawing Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html)

### **Handling events to interact with the user**

- You need to know how to handle events if you are to respond to `double
  tap to zoom` and other related events. See: [Event Handling Guide for
  iOS](https://web.archive.org/web/20160427193652/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

There are a few sample projects that you can check:

[Simple Gesture Recognizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html) which Apple states:

> is a perfect starting point for understanding gesture recognition.
>   This app demonstrates how to recognize tap, swipe, and rotate
>   gestures. The app responds to each gesture by displaying and animating
>   an image at the touch location.

and the [MoveMe](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/MoveMe/) sample which `shows how to animate a view in response to touch events. Examine this sample project to further your understanding of custom touch-event handling.`

### **React to user's current location**

- [Location Awareness Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

  - [Getting the User’s Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

If this is your first iOS or OSX project ever, well, it is quite something. Not the easiest to start, especially if you are not familiar with cocoa-touch event handling and the window/view architecture. However, Apple documentation is very well written and quite straightforward. Ans you will always find somebody to help on SO. Good luck and hang on.

Comment: ,, thanks for the information, I'm getting started immediately, just one more question --> do i need any third party open source animation libraries for this???  Or would the stuff provided by Apple be sufficient?

Comment: Apple will provide you with means to detect tap (events) so you can zoom. You will also be provided with the location of your users (providing that they agree) so you should be good. Beyond that, it depends on what you mean by `If he moves around , it should add more locations`. What are those locations? If you mean adding items like restaurants or stuff like that, you will need to use external services.